# how to use interface for communicatiion among classes and activities

Tags: android, interface

I have a  class and an activity. I need to implement an interface to track whenever there is a change in a variable in class then it should reflect on activity. Can someone please explain how to use interface for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code for reference, create interface to trace event, implement that interface in your activity and set its call back from change var value event of your class.

```
interface ChangeListener{
  public void onVarChanged(String value);
}

class Abc{
  String var ="";
  ChangeListener changeListeners;

  public Abc(ChangeListener changeListeners){
    this.changeListeners = changeListeners;
  }


  public void setVar(String str){
    var = str;
    changeListeners.onVarChanged(var);
  }

}


class MyActivity extends Activity implements ChangeListner{
  /*
  your stuff...........
  */
  onCreate(...){
     Abc abc = new Abc(this);
     abc.setVar("My new string");
  }

  @Override
  public void onVarChanged(String value)
  {
    Log.v("","==== Variable is changed ==== "+value);
  }

}
```

Comment: Hope this will help you, and ask me if there is any query.

Comment: hi naran ,can you tell me how to get the changed value in myactivity

Comment: Take a look at modified answer. Now you can also get modified value.

Answer (score 0):

Observer pattern is the right fit here. Have a look at this http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Observable.html . The activity will be an `Observer` and the other class will be the `Observable`

Comment: Thanks a lot. What you said is absolutely useful. But i need to make a complete interface so i can use it wherever i want. I basically need to learn from scratch how does interface works to communicate between classes and activites. Thanks